# order query results by specific where condition (complex)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The think is to get search result by phrase (search over several columns), and sort priority have to depend on which column there is matching (including exact matching case).

My example works fine, but I still think there is a better way to do it:

```
WITH    products
  AS ( SELECT
        -- .. some columns
        --------- For Sorting -------------
        [sortOrder] = CASE 
            WHEN [partNumber] = @searchPhrase                                                                       
             OR [manPartNumber]= @searchPhrase
            THEN 1                                                                
            WHEN  FormatSiteNameForSearch( [siteName] ) 
                  LIKE '%' + @searchPhrase + '%'
            THEN 2                                                                        
            WHEN [partNumber] LIKE '%' + @searchPhrase + '%'
                 OR [manPartNumber] LIKE '%' + @searchPhrase + '%'
            THEN 3
            ELSE 100
            END
        --------- End For Sorting -------------
        FROM [dbo].[PRODUCTS_Products]           
        WHERE                                                                                                                            
            [partNumber] LIKE '%' + @searchPhrase + '%'
            OR [manPartNumber] LIKE '%'+ @searchPhrase + '%'
            OR FormatSiteNameForSearch([siteName]) LIKE '%'+@searchPhrase+'%'                                                              
            OR [name] LIKE '%'+ @searchPhrase+ '%'                                                                                                                      
    )
    SELECT TOP(10) *
    FROM    products
    ORDER BY sortOrder
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP (10) * 
FROM   [dbo].[PRODUCTS_PRODUCTS] 
WHERE  [PARTNUMBER] LIKE '%' + @searchPhrase + '%' 
        OR [MANPARTNUMBER] LIKE '%' + @searchPhrase + '%' 
        OR Formatsitenameforsearch([SITENAME]) LIKE '%' + @searchPhrase + '%' 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN [PARTNUMBER] = @searchPhrase 
                  OR [MANPARTNUMBER] = @searchPhrase THEN 1 
            WHEN Formatsitenameforsearch([SITENAME]) LIKE 
                 '%' + @searchPhrase + '%' THEN 2 
            WHEN [PARTNUMBER] LIKE '%' + @searchPhrase + '%' 
                  OR [MANPARTNUMBER] LIKE '%' + @searchPhrase + '%' THEN 3 
            ELSE 100 
          END
```